# IN statement in Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to execute IN statement in Eloquent query. I tried this:

```
$id = urldecode($id);

$news = News::whereHas('newsCategories', function($q) use($id)
{
    $q->where('category_id', 'IN', '('.$id.')')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
})->get();
```

But I get empty result.

When I switch `IN` for `=` and pass a number instead of array I get results. Did I do something wrong?

So this works:

```
$id = 2;

$news = News::whereHas('newsCategories', function($q) use($id)
{
    $q->where('category_id', '=', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `whereIn` with an array of your ids to be checked...

```
$news = News::whereHas('newsCategories', function($q) use($array_of_ids)
{
    $q->whereIn('category_id', $array_of_ids)
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
})->get();
```

Just make sure that you're passing in something that is truly an array :)