# getting database results from an array of ids

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm using Laravel. I have an ids array of the table brands:

```
$brand_ids = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'];
```

I'm trying to fetch the name of the brand through these ids however I can't seem to find an efficient way to do this.

```
foreach($brand_ids as $brand_id){
    $brand_name = $this->model->select('name', 'id')->where('id', '=', $brand_id);
}
```

This works but seems really inefficient when calling the same query 7 times. I've been trying to figure out a way to use the sql IN statement but I can't seem to figure out how to use it with an array.

Comment: `whereIn` is what you want!  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069611/in-statement-in-eloquent/25069635

Comment: @msturdy thank you if you wanna answer it ill give you the check

Comment: already posted the answer there :)  Just upvote it if it helps you out!